# CentOS 6.5 doesn't start

Tags: linux, boot

I installed CentOS 6.5 on my laptop, 2.0-GHz Celeron mobile, 1GB RAM, 120GB HD. The installation finishes without a problem. When I'm asked to reboot the system, I click reboot and I get a black screen with a flickering dash when the laptop restarts. I tried to find the system requirements for CentOS 6.5 but couldn't find it.

I was advised to press  ESC as soon as CentOS 2.6.32-358.e16.i686 starts in xx seconds shows up, then press a to edit kernel options, remove rghb quiet and type nomodeset and press enter.

I tried again, it started, message kept on scrolling then went back blank.

Was advised again to use nomodeset 3

again, it started, message kept on scrolling then went back blank.

The last three lines that show up before it goes blank are:

IPMI BT : timeout in XACTION [H2B]
failed 2 retries, sending error response
IPMI : BT reset (takes 5 secs)

I'm new to linux ,so please, try to detail you answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you see something like that (see below) in the logs (this is from
CentOS 5.3), that means IPMI is not working properly, basically
Dell OpenManage is not working properly, I guess you have an old dell laptop.

After few weeks with those IPMI errors machine will freeze (kernel
2.6.18). It's really annoying, as on DRAC power options are
greyed-out[#ref1] when IPMI timeout errors are occurring. The only way
to bring the box back to life after freeze is to physically power cycle
it. Remotely it is not possible to do that (magic sysrq can help, but
not always). That still doesn't help for IPMI errors. After reboot IPMI
errors are back straight away. To get rid of those errors (for a short
while, about a week) you need to unplug the laptop from power, wait 20
seconds, and power it back. But they will come back. Maybe a week, maybe
two weeks, but you will see them again. After few weeks (months) server
will start giving OOM-killer errors, and machine will freeze again.

A while ago I've updated the BMC firmware from 1.73 to 1.84 on two
testing machines which had those errors, and so far so good. No issues,
timeouts are gone. Sounds simple, firmware update, but took me some time
to figure that out.

Here are some examples of those IPMI errors:

IPMI BT: timeout in XACTION [ B_BUSY H2B ] failed 2 retries, sending error response
IPMI: BT reset (takes 5 secs)
IPMI BT: timeout in XACTION [ B_BUSY H2B ] failed 2 retries, sending error response
IPMI: BT reset (takes 5 secs)
IPMI BT: timeout in XACTION [ B_BUSY H2B ] failed 2 retries, sending error response
IPMI: BT reset (takes 5 secs)
IPMI BT: timeout in XACTION [ B_BUSY H2B ] failed 2 retries, sending error response
IPMI: BT reset (takes 5 secs)
IPMI BT: timeout in XACTION [ B_BUSY H2B ] failed 2 retries, sending error response
IPMI: BT reset (takes 5 secs)

Comment: Optionally, see if you can disable the IPMI/BMC within the BIOS. It might be called IPMI, BMC or OpenManage.